# Can not open Eclipse IDE after update form Luna to Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, updates, eclipse-mars

I updated eclipse Luna to Mars.
What I did is ...

- Add mars url to `Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites`
- `Help > Check for Updates`
- Followed what the wizard indicated
- Installed successfully and a pop up showed that I have to reopen this application(Eclipse)

And now, when I trying to open eclipse, A pop up message shows. It said "Can not open this application" and no other any Informations.

It seems like update successfully, so I do not have any idea what is wrong is it. How can I fix or got some clues about this situation? 
Thanks

FYI, I attach my `eclipse.ini` and result of `java -version`.

This is ini file

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-javaagent:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.zeroturnaround.eclipse.optimizer.plugin_1.0.6/agent/eclipse-optimizer-agent.jar
-Xverify:none
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

And my version is ...

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Use [this link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F) to find the logs it generates and put the relevant part here.

Comment: It looks like A project fail log. But my problem is not about specified project. It is about eclipse itself. When I click the icon on the file explorer, it says can not open this application. I found some log files in eclipse package(It is in Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/), but it seems not relevant.(And my problem happens today, but there is no today's log)

Comment: From experience, I learnt that unlike most software, Eclipse doesn't play well with major release upgrades. It can easily break and have a lot of problems if you upgrade from one major release (like Luna) to another (like Mars). I find it better to just leave it at the current major release. You don't really gain much by upgrading. If you want to upgrade, it's easier to do a clean install, and export/import your customizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [What's New in Mars](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/platform.php):

> For Mars (4.5), the Eclipse SDK for OS X is now distributed in a more
>   standard "Mac App" format, instead of the "directory format" we have
>   used in the past.
>
> **CAUTION**: Current Mac users can not use "update" to Mars. In fact,
>   doing so will break your installation! You need to start with a fresh
>   download.
>
> In the event that you updated before reading this, and have ended up
>   with a broken installation, see [Issues related to Mac App
>   installations](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Issues_related_to_Mac_App_installations)
>   for the steps to recover your installation, after getting a fresh
>   download.

So you need to do a new Install (your workspace should be OK).

Comment: Uh. Thanks :-) As what you mentioned I found the directories structure has been changed a lot. (inside of Eclips.app directory)